# Expected red rectangle in frame, see nothing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, java-2d, thread-sleep

Here's the code:

Class aa

```
package com.MahBonnets.Game;

import javax.swing.*;

public class aa {

public static ab f = new ab();
public static int width = 600;
public static int height = 400;
public static void main(String args[]) {
        f.setSize(width, height);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setTitle("MAH BONNETS IS GONE");
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        System.out.println("Running!!");
}
}
```

ab

```
package com.MahBonnets.Game;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ab extends JFrame {

public ac panel;

public ab() {
    panel = new ac(this);
    setLayout(new GridLayout (1, 1, 0, 0));
    add(panel);
}
}
```

And ac

```
package com.MahBonnets.Game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.*;

public class ac extends JPanel implements Runnable {
public Rectangle floor;

public int floorheight = 80;
public int fps = 1000;

public boolean objectDefine = false;

public Thread game;
public ac(ab f) {
    setBackground(Color.black);

    defineObjects();

    game = new Thread(this);
    game.start(); }

void defineObjects() {
        floor = new Rectangle(-10, aa.height-floorheight, aa.width+10, floorheight);
        objectDefine = true;
        repaint();
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);

    if(objectDefine) {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(floor.x, floor.y, floor.width, floor.height);
}
}


public void fpsSetter() {
try{
    Thread.sleep(fps/1000); 
}catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

        }

  }
  @Override
  public void run(){
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }
}
```

What isn't happening that's supposed to be happening is that a red rectangle is supposed to appear at the bottom of the JFrame. I'm entirely new to programming, but I've looked over the section of code pertaining to the rectangle and everything looks in order... at least... as far as I can tell.

If you have any idea what's wrong please help me out. Thanks.

Here's the youtube tutorial I've been following http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0lfhcKAIr-8

Comment: pls give a meaningful `title` to your post..helps in reading.

Comment: `public class aa` .. `ab` .. `ac`..  What is this, premature obfuscation?  Please give a meaningful name to classes, attributes and methods.  After all, source code is for *human* consumption.  ;)

Comment: You forgot to do `f.pack(); f.setVisible(true);`

Comment: Change `public class ac extends JPanel implements Runnable {
..
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);` to `public class ac extends JPanel implements Runnable {
..
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g); // For Swing JComponents`

Comment: try to debug, print some useful messages in some important steps, put something equivalent to `assert` in C. then follow the execution steps. Stumbling in first steps is granted, but not giving up is expected.

Comment: You got this off YouTube? Get you're money back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't rely on magic numbers...
2. Don't rely on parameters that may not match reality (`public static int width = 600` isn't going to be the same size as your child component).  Use `getWidth` and `getHeight` to get the actual size of your component...
3. Get rid of your `defineObjects` and rely on actually known states of your component
4. Get rid of your `paint` method and use `paintComponent` instead
5. `static` is not always your friend
6. Don't use YouTube as a reference, unless the poster has references ;)
7. Do read [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
8. Do read [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)
9. Do read [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Replace your `paint` method with something more like this...

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.

    int x = -10;
    int y = getHeight() - floorheight;
    int width = getWidth() + 10;
    int height = floorheight;
    floor = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(floor.x, floor.y, floor.width, floor.height);
}
```

And `Thread.sleep(1000 / 1000)` is as close to no sleep as makes no difference ;) - 25fps is rough 40 milliseconds ;)

Comment: Thanks fellas. I'll be trying all of these thing. Don't worry, I wont give up. :)

Comment: @user2353375 The only way to fail is to give up ;)

Answer (score 2):

Do not override `paint(Graphics g)`. try overridding `paintComponent(Graphics g)`

Answer (score 2):

In your "aa" class, instead of a static instance of ab (the line: public static ab f = new ab();), try using a variable local to the main method. Like:

```
//public static ab f = new ab();
public static int width = 600;
public static int height = 400;
public static void main(String args[]) {
        ab f = new ab(); // local var
        f.setSize(width, height);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setTitle("MAH BONNETS IS GONE");
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        System.out.println("Running!!");
}
```

Alternatively, you could remove the static references to aa.width and aa.height from the defineObjects() method in the "ac" class.

```
floor = new Rectangle(-10, aa.height-floorheight, aa.width+10, floorheight); //take out the static references !!!
```

Do a simple test to understand the reason. Before making any changes, print the values of aa.width and aa.height, you'll see that they are zero.